# Xarray ValueError: When combine='by_coords', passing a value for `concat_dim` has no effect

Tags: python-xarray

This script worked before, but not any more. I got the below message and can't figure out how to fix it.

I have installed metpy and act-atmos.
I have tried to clean the environment and reinstalled the packages (metpy and act-atmos). Nothing helps.

Any suggestions?? Thank you so much in advance.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [6], line 3
      1 # Read in some data with wind speed/direction in the file
      2 #filenames = glob.glob('sgpmetE13.b1/sgpmetE13.b1.20210301.000000.cdf')
----> 3 obj = act.io.armfiles.read_netcdf('sgpmetE13.b1/*')
      5 WindDisplay = act.plotting.WindRoseDisplay(obj, figsize=(8, 10), subplot_shape=(1,))
      6 WindDisplay.plot('wdir_vec_mean', 'wspd_vec_mean', spd_bins=np.linspace(0, 25, 5),
      7     num_dirs=30, tick_interval=2, subplot_index=(0,))

File D:\Anac3\envs\aaf\Lib\site-packages\act\io\armfiles.py:141, in read_netcdf(filenames, concat_dim, return_None, combine, use_cftime, cftime_to_datetime64, **kwargs)
    137         arm_ds = xr.open_mfdataset(filenames, **kwargs)
    139     else:
    140         # When all else fails raise the orginal exception
--> 141         raise exception
    143 # Xarray has issues reading a CF formatted time units string if it contains
    144 # timezone offset without a [+|-] preceeding timezone offset.
    145 # https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/3644
   (...)
    149 # does not preserve the time past ms precision. We will use ms precision for
    150 # the conversion.
    151 desired_time_precision = 'datetime64[ms]'

File D:\Anac3\envs\aaf\Lib\site-packages\act\io\armfiles.py:119, in read_netcdf(filenames, concat_dim, return_None, combine, use_cftime, cftime_to_datetime64, **kwargs)
    115     except_tuple = except_tuple + (FileNotFoundError, OSError)
    117 try:
    118     # Read data file with Xarray function
--> 119     arm_ds = xr.open_mfdataset(filenames, **kwargs)
    121 except except_tuple as exception:
    122     # If requested return None for File not found error
    123     if type(exception).__name__ == 'FileNotFoundError':

File D:\Anac3\envs\aaf\Lib\site-packages\xarray\backends\api.py:976, in open_mfdataset(paths, chunks, concat_dim, compat, preprocess, engine, data_vars, coords, combine, parallel, join, attrs_file, combine_attrs, **kwargs)
    971     ids, paths = (
    972         list(combined_ids_paths.keys()),
    973         list(combined_ids_paths.values()),
    974     )
    975 elif combine == "by_coords" and concat_dim is not None:
--> 976     raise ValueError(
    977         "When combine='by_coords', passing a value for `concat_dim` has no "
    978         "effect. To manually combine along a specific dimension you should "
    979         "instead specify combine='nested' along with a value for `concat_dim`.",
    980     )
    982 open_kwargs = dict(engine=engine, chunks=chunks or {}, **kwargs)
    984 if parallel:

ValueError: When combine='by_coords', passing a value for `concat_dim` has no effect. To manually combine along a specific dimension you should instead specify combine='nested' along with a value for `concat_dim`.
```

Comment: you just need to decide how you want to combine the data, and provide the correct arguments. check out the guide to [combining data](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/user-guide/combining.html). to help, we'd need to know more about how you're trying to combine the files, and what their structure is. but it should just be a matter of deciding how you're combining the files, passing the correct argument to `combine`, and then providing any additional arguments, such as `concat_dim` if `combine='nested'`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.  This error happened after the jupyter lab crashed. Before that, I never see this error message and the script ran smoothly. Maybe it is not the xarray issue?

Comment: The issue was fixed. The ACT package support python 3.10, not 3.11 yet.  This error is caused by the package mismatching.